# Parse tabulated key-value pairs to set shell variables

Tags: text-processing, ksh

I have the following table:

```
san0    san1    san2    san3    san4    san5    san6    san7 
6.36%   6.24%   6.24%   6.24%   6.33%   6.25%   6.25%   6.25%
```

I need to parse this table to import the values into shell variables, i.e. the label in the first row should become a shell variable with a value from the corresponding field in the second row.

So, variable `san0` will be `6.36%`, `san4` will be `6.33%` etc.

I tried many tools but sometimes people get stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

```
      #!/bin/bash
      #first you take the input of the file, in two separate strings
      IFS=$'\n'
      {
      read line1
      read line2
      } < yourfile
   
      #then you create arrays out of the strings, by modifying IFS to        
      IFS=$'\t'
      a=($(echo "$line1"))
      b=($(echo "$line2"))

      if [[ ${#a[@]} -eq ${#b[@]} ]] #if you want no var to be empty
      then
         num=0
         while [[ -n "${a[$num]}" ]]
         do
              declare -g "$(echo ${a[$num]})"="$(echo ${b[$num]})"
              ((num++))
         done
      fi
```

now you can call your vars either by name or indirectly as ${!a[0]}
etc

Answer (score 1):

Create the variable assignments with `awk` and source the output using a process substitution.

```
. <(awk -F'\t' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (FNR==1) a[i]=$i; else print a[i] "=" $i }' file)
```

The same with GNU `datamash`:

```
. <(datamash --output-delimiter== transpose <file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
cols=8
declare $(awk -vcols=$cols -vRS= '{while (i++<cols) print $i"="$(i+cols)}' file)
```

```
echo "$san7"
6.25%
```